# Is there any evidence of language contact between the Inuit and Ainu languages?

Tags: comparative-linguistics, language-contact, ainu

The Eskimo-Aleut and Ainu languages were historically spoken in the same region (near the Kamchatka Peninsula), and they share some features that are common in [Paleo-Siberian languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleosiberian_languages), including [incorporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incorporation_(linguistics)).

I have also noticed that the native name of the Greenlandic Inuit language (Inuktitut) is similar to the name of the Ainu language (Aynu=itak). In both of these languages, these words means "human language," although I do not know whether this is a coincidence.

Have there been any comparative studies of the Eskimo-Aleut and Ainu languages to identify possible cognates between them?

Comment: The only well regarded link between old and new world languages are the [Dené–Yeniseian languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Den%C3%A9%E2%80%93Yeniseian_languages), which don't include either. But that's in terms of language family links, not borrowings. Borrowings through language contact is much more likely, and we have evidence of that between Polynesian and Quechua.

Comment: Also, note that Inuktitut is only one language in the Eskimo–Aleut language family, and other members of that family are closer to Japan.

Comment: Another surprising lack of linguistic relation: Inuit and Innu, in a similar area and having a history of contact... As for "human language", many people groups have names for themselves that mean "the people" and that naturally extends to tautological names for their language.

Comment: @curiousdannii What? Polynesian and Quechua? Kon-tiki for real (or rather the other direction)? Link please!

Comment: @Mitch See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-Columbian_trans-oceanic_contact_theories#Linguistics

Comment: Inuktitut is not Greenlandic – it’s Canadian. There is really no such thing as “the Greenlandic Inuit language” (there are several Inuit languages spoken in Greenland), but the native name of the official and most widely spoken one, West Greenlandic, is **Kalaallisut** (from _kalaallit_ ‘(West) Greenlander’, probably from Norse _Skrælingi_ so an exonym in origin).